# can't create domain name bucket whereas I successfully put the google html file

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've successfully used gsutil to create a domain name bucket, with the html file method.

But with another domain, I did put the html file on the site and GWT validation passed, but I still cant create the bucket : gsutil says the domain is owned by another user.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that the account you used to create the domain and the account you are using to create the bucket are the same account?

Comment: I guess so : when I sign in with the google account I can see all domains in GWT with "verification succeeded" mention. While denying gsutil provides a link which ask to use dns method, which I would rather not use, also I'd like the html method to work, since it works for other domains.